# Pyspark : Filter dataframe based on null values in two columns

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe like this

```
id    customer_name     city       order
1     John              dallas      5
2     steve                         4
3                       austin      3
4     Ryan              houston     2
5                                   6
6     nyle              austin      4
```

I want to filter out the rows where customer_name and city are both null. If one of them have value then they should not get filtered. Result should be

```
id    customer_name     city       order
1     John              dallas      5
2     steve                         4
3                       austin      3
4     Ryan              houston     2
6     nyle              austin      4
```

I can only find out the filter condition based on one column. How to filter based on two columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.filter(coalesce('customer_name', 'city').isNotNull())
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will work by using these and f alias for functions.

```
df.filter(f.col("customer_name").isNotNull() & f.col("city").isNotNull())
```